# ADLS Gen-2. Get AuthorizationPermissionMismatch error from PUT requst about creating new filesystem by postman

Tags: java, azure, postman, azure-data-lake

I login to adls gen 2 by these POST request:

[https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%3Ctenant_id%3E/oauth2/v2.0/token)

Request body:

> grant_type:client_credentials
>
> client_id: my_client_id from App registrations -> Owned applications
>   -> Mu application
>
> client_secret: my_client_secret from App registrations -> Owned
>   applications -> My application
>
> scope: https://storage.azure.com/.default
>
> provider_type:
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider

And get successfull responce code 200:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "access_token": <token>
}
```

After I tryed to create filesystem by using following PUT request:
https://dbmiadlsgen2.dfs.core.windows.net/mydata?resource=filesystem

Headers:

> Authorization - Bearer 
>   Content-Type - text/plain x-ms-version - 2018-11-09

And get folloing error:

```
    {
        "error": {
            "code": "AuthorizationPermissionMismatch",
            "message": "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.\nRequestId:bcb4c0d3-901f-00cc-0722-2b7f0c000000\nTime:2019-06-25T06:54:57.3437434Z"
        }

}
```

I get grand to my user from azure portal:
Storage Blob Data Contributor role, but it is not help...

How do you think what kind of role I should use? 
Are some request body or header parameters incorrect? 
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with java, but here is an [example](http://sql.pawlikowski.pro/2019/03/10/connecting-to-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-from-powershell-using-rest-api-a-step-by-step-guide/) of how to create filesystem using rest api with powershell. You can follow it and have a try. I did follow this article with python and c#, and worked for me.

Comment: thank you very much, I tried to implement in java, but it is not work for me, therefore I used OAuth authrorization. May be in the future microsoft will represent sdk for java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not enough for the app and account to be added as owners, I would suggest you to go to your `storage account > IAM > Add role and add the special permission` for this type of request, `STORAGE BLOB DATA CONTRIBUTOR` .

For further reference please visit:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you very much. I added STORAGE BLOB DATA CONTRIBUTOR for my owned application and after It worked. Before I added this role for only  my account to login in azure.portal